# checkbox submit on href (html)

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to submit a form without a submit button but when I click on another href.
Here is my code :

**Page 1 :**

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="page2.php"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="condition" value="1">
</form>
<a href="page2.php?item=n" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit();"> link </a>
```

**Page 2 :**

```
 $_SESSION['condition'] = isset($_POST['condition'])? 1 : 0;
```

The problem is that `$_POST['condition']`  is never set, even when the box is checked.. It seems that my form is not submited from page1 to page2. Do you have any clue why that could happen ?

**Edit :**

Maybe it wasn't clear what I was trying to achieve so I edited my code : I am using href because I have a list of ref on which the user can click but I wanted to add an option with the checkbox. So I want to send the option with the arguments of the ref when the user clicks on the ref.

Comment: set "action" in your form to "page2.php" thats where the form will be submitted.

Comment: action attribute of form should be page2.php, not the href

Comment: Why are you using a link to submit the form instead of a button with a type of submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<a href="page2.php?item=n" onclick="document.forms['myform'].attributes.action.value = this.attributes.href.value; document.forms['myform'].submit(); return false;"> link </a>
```

Comment: the "return false" generates a "url not found" statement

Comment: ups sorry my bad I spelled one word wrong. It works !!
But I am not sure of how it work... What is it doing ?

Comment: It copies the href attribute into form's action attribute, and then submits the form. The return false; part does not allow browser to follow the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

the submit() method uses the specified action of the form as target, not the href of your link, you should remove that

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="page2.php"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="condition" value="1">
</form>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit();"> link </a>
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear enough. I still want the link specified in the href to be the one called, but I also need to send the option from the checkbox. (maybe the checkbox is not the right item to use for my purpose though)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="page2.php?item=n"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="condition" value="1">
    <button type="submit" class="link">link</button>
</form>
```

You can style the button to look like a link by removing the border and adjusting the font.